# clion run cmake on each build

Tags: c++, c, cmake, clion

I am not sure if its possible to do this with clion, I was testing out the program and enjoy using it to write c code because the ctags and etags support is really nice.

I am copying some files over from the cmake source tree to the bin location on each build. While using clion if I update some of the files that I am copying the results aren't updated within clion.

If I instead go back to the terminal and just run the typical cmake steps

```
cmake ../ && make && bin/./program
```

that copies the updated files and I am able to see my results.

This is the CMake command that I am using in my build.

```
FILE(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/resources/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin/resources/)
```

I might be able to restructure the cmake command to make it copy every time or it might just be a clion issue. I am unsure and would like to be able to take care of this all from within clion, instead of going back to the terminal to run the cmake command for updates to take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want CMake to make some action whenever some file is changed, you should create a rule using `add_custom_command` and pass file via `DEPENDS` argument. Note, that only file-level dependencies are supported by CMake, for make dependency on directory you need to list all files in it.

```
# Collect list of files within directory.
FILES(GLOB files_list RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/resources/
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/resources/*") 
# This will contain full paths to files in binary directory. 
set(binary_files_list)
foreach(file ${files_list})
    set(source_file ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/resources/${file})
    set(binary_file ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin/resources/${file})
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${binary_file}
        COMMAND cmake -E ${source_file} ${binary_file}
        DEPENDS ${source_file})
    list(APPEND binary_files_list ${binary_file})
endforeach()
add_custom_target(resources DEPENDS ${binary_files_list})
```

Note, that in case of adding/removing files you should to run `cmake` explicitely. That's why hardcoded files list is preferred to `GLOB`ing.

Comment: one ore question, since I know which files I am accessing in my source code. Is there a way to make a list of files and pass those out to cmake which can then be used? for example in my c code I make reference to filea.txt, can I have this be passed back to cmake? Then instead of globbing the files I just have the build automatically read a list of files and update accordingly?

Comment: You may create file which looks like `set(files_list ...)` and `include` it from CMakeLists.txt. Whenever this file will be changed (e.g. while building project), next `make` call will trigger reconfigure step. If you need more detailed info, please, ask new question.

Comment: thanks, i'll ask a new question if I cannot get it sorted out.